# Get Cakephp 3 display true/false for booleans

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using cakephp 3, I have a boolean [tinyint(1)] in a table, and the edit and add templates have a check box on the form, but how do I get the index and view templates to display a string like true/false or yes/no instead of 1/0.  Do I map them over in the controller actions, or is there a option I can add to the templates?

Answer (score 6):

The answers given both work fine.

I created a Helper class in `/src/View/Helper/FormatBooleanHelper.php` as below:

```
<?php
/*
* FormatBooleanHelper
*
* CakePHP Helper created to format boolean values in either Yes/No or True/False text.
* By:  Jared Testa
*
*/

namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;

class FormatBooleanHelper extends Helper
{

/**
 * yesNo method
 *
 * @param boolean| $value boolean
 * @return string
 *
 */

public function yesNo($value, $showNo = true) {
    return ($value) ? "Yes" : (($showNo) ? "No" : "");
}

/**
 * trueFalse method
 *
 * @param boolean| $value boolean
 * @return string
 *
 */

public function trueFalse($value, $showFalse = true) {
    return ($value) ? "True" : (($showFalse) ? "False" : "");
}

}

?>
```

The helper is used in the standard convention by including `$this->loadHelper('FormatBoolean');` in your initialize method in the AppView.php file.

You then use the Helper in your view by including `$this->FormatBoolean->yesNo($booleanVariable)` or `$this->FormatBoolean->yesNo($booleanVariable, false)` in your view.  The latter example will leave the field blank in a false response.

Overkill?  Perhaps...but I think it fits into the CakePHP structure, and it was a good exercise in creating your own helper.

I'm using the helper in CakePHP version 3.3.4.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I use a [helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormatHelper.php#L389) to display icons with some titles here by default, one can easily adjust his [bake templates](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-setup/blob/master/docs/Console/Bake.md) for this :)

Comment: This isn't overkill, this is programming! Now if you decide you actually want to display yes/no in lower case, upper case, as true/false whatever you are only changing it in one place rather than hundreds of places. Great answer.

Answer (score 3):

simply:

```
<?= ($var)?'yes':'no' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go in to display the data you can choose to display a string instead of the int. This is a simplified approach since you didn't provide any code or other information:

In the view, $isTrue being the boolean:

```
<?php if($isTrue){echo "true";}else{echo "false";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added (for bottom, jtesta answer) method to get graphically representation - "check" or "x" using Foundation Icon Fonts 3:

```
public function checkX($value, $showFalse = true) {
    return ($value) ? '<i class="fi-check"></i>' : (($showFalse) ? '<i class="fi-x"></i>' : '');
}
```

[Image how it loks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPmYS.jpg)